# The development server returned error code 504 react native emulator

Tags: react-native, remote-debugging

I am working on react native in a windows system and i am unable to connect to the remote debugger. it returns with a 504 bad gateway timeout error code. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**hello , fast solution is : [this](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/401)**

1 - delete node_modules folder

2 - edit package json : react-native version to "55.4" or "55.2" and babel-preset-react-native to "4.0.0"

3 - run npm install or yarn install command

4 - you're done

Comment: But it was working perfectly till last friday and today only i got this error

Comment: its seems some dependency issues try those it will resolve

Comment: But I havnt found a package named " babel-preset-react-native" inside my pakage.json.  Is this "metro-react-native-babel-preset" instead?

Comment: can you post package.json

Comment: {
  "name": "jwsk-anv",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint *.js **/*.js",
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  }

Comment: ,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1"
  },

Comment: "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.3.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.3.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "24.5.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "jest": "24.5.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.53.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}

Comment: Delete babel-preset-react-native folder inside node_modules and then install older version 2.1.0 of this library with npm install babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0 --save-dev. remove metro-react-native-babel-preset